VScode inputs \u{A8} instead of double quote and \u{B4} instead of single quote
I'm using a linux system. only inside  VSCode, this issue occures.
VScode inputs \u{A8} instead of double quote and \u{B4} instead of single quote
checked the vscode settings. not sure where to find this.
pressing ' gives ´
pressing " gives ¨

What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

i was using mobaxterm to connect to linux. restarting the x server, fixed the issue. The default keyboard layout is the issue.
